# ASP.NET Core Incorrect Route for LoginPath

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc, cookie-authentication

I have two controllers in the `Controllers` folder: `HomeController` and `LoginController`.

I am using cookie authentication and set the `LoginPath` to `/Login`, expecting it to route to the `LoginController`.

However, when I click on the login link, the app routes to `Home/Login` instead of `/Login`. How can it get it to route to `/Login` correctly?

**Routes**

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "login",
    pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Login}");
```

LoginPath:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Denied";
});
```

Folders:

[image: Folders]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the codes `options.LoginPath = "/Login";` would redirect you to `https://localhost:xxxx/Login` when you visit the endpoint has Authrize attribute on it if you're not authenticated;If the Login Action is in Login Controller,For your requirement,it should be `"/Login/Login"`

Secondly,

> However, when I click on the login link, the app routes to Home/Login

it depends on how you configured the link,but you haven't show it.

you need a link like:`<a asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Login"> Login </a>`

And the second route parttern  you configured is not necessary

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for more details